# GooglePlay services build error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I updated build tools, and can not compile my app.
I always got an error -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processProdDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
> >     available at
> >     https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
> >     or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

my build.gradle-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        //method count
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/supersonic/android-sdk" }
        maven {
            url "https://clojars.org/repo" }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

project.ext {
    versionCode = 14
    versionName = "1.1.0.3"

    minSdkVersion = 15
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    sdkTools = '22.0.1'
    appcompatVer = "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1"
}
```

my app/build.gradle

```
def final UNIVERSAL_IMAGE_LOADER = '1.9.5'
def final MULTIVIEW_PAGER_VER = '1.0'
def final ACTIVE_ANDROID_VER = '3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
def final CIRCLE_IMAGE_VER = '1.3.0';
def final OKHTTP_VER = '2.4.0';
def final EMOJI_VERSION = '1.0'
def final FACEBOOK_SDK_VER = '4.1.0'
def final ROUNDED_IMAGEVIEW_VER = '2.2.1'
def final GSM_VER = '9.0.0'
def final RECYCLER_VIEW_VER = '23.1.1'
def final FLURRY_VER = '6.2.0'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//uncomment this and in top-gradle file to count num of refs
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dexcount {
    includeClasses = true
    includeFieldCount = true
    printAsTree = true
    orderByMethodCount = true
    verbose = true
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.sdkTools

    packagingOptions {
        //this resolves SignalR and Protobuf conflict
        //start region
        exclude 'package-list'
        exclude 'index.html'
        exclude 'help-doc.html'
        exclude 'constant-values.html'
        exclude 'allclasses-noframe.html'
        exclude 'allclasses-frame.html'
        exclude 'resources/tab.gif'
        exclude 'resources/background.gif'
        exclude 'resources/titlebar.gif'
        exclude 'resources/titlebar_end.gif'
        exclude 'stylesheet.css'
        exclude 'overview-tree.html'
        //end region
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dating.social.viche"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../my-release-key.keystore")
            storePassword "qwertysocialapp123"
            keyAlias "egoistapp"
            keyPassword "qwertysocialapp123"
        }

        qainvalid{
            storeFile file("../debug.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug{
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-debug-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {

            lintOptions{
                //to fix google error - google_id is not translated to other lang
                checkReleaseBuilds false
            }

            minifyEnabled true

//            debuggable false
//            jniDebuggable false
//            renderscriptDebuggable false
//            zipAlignEnabled true


            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        qa {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.qainvalid
            String versionName1 = rootProject.ext.versionName + '_QA'
            versionName versionName1
        }
        prod {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile project(':signalr-client-sdk-android')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${RECYCLER_VIEW_VER}"
    compile "com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:${UNIVERSAL_IMAGE_LOADER}"
    compile "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:${CIRCLE_IMAGE_VER}"
    compile "com.pixplicity.multiviewpager:library:${MULTIVIEW_PAGER_VER}"
    compile "com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:${ACTIVE_ANDROID_VER}"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:${OKHTTP_VER}"
    compile "com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:${EMOJI_VERSION}"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:${FACEBOOK_SDK_VER}"
    compile "com.makeramen:roundedimageview:${ROUNDED_IMAGEVIEW_VER}"
    compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.2@aar'

    compile "com.flurry.android:analytics:${FLURRY_VER}"

    compile 'com.supersonic.sdk:mediationsdk:6.4.6@jar'

    compile project(':apng_lib')
    compile project(':flingCards')

    //SignalR libraries
    //    To get updated libs, make project and grab resourses : https://github.com/SignalR/java-client
    //    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    //    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    //    compile files ('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
    //    compile files ('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
    //    compile "org.java-websocket:java-websocket:1.3.1"

    //    To generate new version of proto Java classes refer to tools/readme
    compile files('libs/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar')

    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:${GSM_VER}'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4';
    }
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${GSM_VER}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${GSM_VER}"
}
```

I need compile sdk 22, because I did not implemented features from 6 android.
Please help

Comment: you go ahead and download latest version and then set sdk app build.gradle

Comment: Which gradle task are you running when you get this error?  `assembleDebug`, or are you building for release?